# CustomProjectSystem folder not created when deploying VSIX Project Type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsix, vspackage, vs-extensibility

**Description**

Using CPS (see [link 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512961.aspx) and [link 2](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem)), I have created a new project type (let say `*.myproj`) for Visual Studio: `File > New Project > Visual C# > Extensibility > Project Type`

When debugging, everything is fine. However, when I deploy (install) the `vsix` package to another PC, and try to create a new project ('.myproj') using the *custom project template* (myproj), I get the following error:

[image: Runtime error in Visual Studio when trying to create a new project using the custom project template.]

The reason is in the `ProjectType.myproj` in the `ProjectTemplate` we have this code:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <CustomProjectExtensionsPath>
        $(LocalAppData)\CustomProjectSystems\ProjectType4\
    </CustomProjectExtensionsPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="$(CustomProjectExtensionsPath)CustomProject.Default.props" />

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'" Label="Configuration">
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'" Label="Configuration">
</PropertyGroup>
```

I figured, after building and running the project Visual Studio, this folder and it's files will be created:

- `(LocalAppData)\CustomProjectSystems\ProjectType4\`
- `CustomPrject.Default.props`
- `CustomProject.props`

**Problem**

However, when I install my vspackage on another PC for the first time, this folder and it's files are not automatically created, hence, the runtime error in the screenshot.

**Workaround**

- I manually copy this files to the other PC then it works fine.
- I remove those lines of code mentioned above, (this will cause to not to be able to use my own icon for the project node. since VS won't release the project type.)

**Question**

- Why these files are not automatically copied to the clients machine?
- Is there any specific settings or configurations that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this is an issue: [Project types should not require MSI to deploy build authoring](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/issues/24)